# Grab Single Frame From Gazebo Camera

Tags: gazebo, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Gazebo 2.2.3 along with ROS Indigo. I also have a robot with a mounted camera in Gazebo. I was wondering if there is a way to just grab a single frame from the robot's camera (not live feed) using ROS. It doesn't even have to display the image like with the image_view command.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192057/grab-single-frame-from-gazebo-camera/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/18898/k.-zeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-09-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe there is no pre-made plugin that does exactly what you´re asking for. You basically have two practical options:

- Write your own Gazebo plugin,
  possibly based on a existing one like
  [gazebo_ros_camera](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/hydro-devel/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_camera.cpp).
  This gives you most control over what
  is actually done in Gazebo (short of
  diving into Gazebo´s sources
  themselves)
- Create a ROS node that subscribes to (stream)
  data from a existing camera plugin
  and just forward data selectively.

The latter option certainly is the easier one to implement and would be preferred if you can live with a few wasted CPU cycles.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/18898/k.-zeng/) on 2014-09-09**:
I understand. Now, I have an existing node that uses the gazebo/apply_joint_effort rosservice call to move my robot model. I'm assuming that it would be more practical if I just wrote a new node to stream camera data rather than trying to modify my current node to do so as well as moving the model?